# Identify child of a child process?

Tags: c, fork

How to identify between a child process and its child?

```
 pid_t pid = fork();
 if (pid == 0) // child 1
 {
   int pid2 = fork(); 
   if (pid2 == 0)// child of child 1
   { ....
```

How do we differentiate between child 1 and its child ? They both have the same pid 0 ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The grandchild will have both `pid` and `pid2` be 0. The direct child will have only `pid` be 0.

Comment: If `pid2` is zero, then you are in the "grandchild", the child of the child. It doesn't matter when or where you call `fork`, or how deeply you go with the number of children. If `fork` returns zero then you are in the child process of the process that called `fork`.

Comment: Yes, but is there some id that identify at which level we are ? is this the first or the nth child ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `fork()` return value: 
>   0 - in child process; 
>   PID -> child PID in parent process; -1 -> error

You can get PID in child process by `getpid()`

```
 if (pid == 0) {
   pid_t child_pid = getpid();
 }
```

Your code with some details:

```
 pid_t pid = fork();
 if (pid == 0) // child 1
 {
   // child process
   pid_t p = getpid(); // Child process pid
   int pid2 = fork(); 
   if (pid2 == 0) { 
     // child of child process
     pid_t p = getpid(); // Child of child process pid
   } else if (pid2 > 0) {
     // Still child process
     //pid2 -> child of child PID
   }
 } else if (pid > 0) {
   // Still main process
   // pid -> child PID
   pid_t p = getpid(); // Main process pid
 }
```